# How do I pick 4 different texts from an arraylist without repitition

Tags: java, android

The app works fine, but the answers on the buttons are sometimes repeating themselves.

How can I prevent that from happening?

This is what have tried so far.

```
public class RiddleGuessActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView riddleQuestionTextView;
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4;

    ArrayList<String> riddles = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
    int locationOfCorrectAnswers = 0,incorrectAnswers;
    int riddleCounter = 0;
    ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();

    public void generateRiddles () {

        riddles.add("I kiss my mother before i die. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("It is greater than God and more evil than the devil. The poor have it, the rich need it and if you eat it you'll die. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("It walks on four legs in the morning, two legs at noon and three legs in the evening. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("I am the beginning of the end, and the end of time and space. I am essential to creation and i surround everyplace. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("What always runs but never walks, often murmurs, never talks, has a bed but never sleeps, has a mouth but never eats. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("At night they come without being fetched, By day they are lost without being stolen. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("The one who makes it, sells it. The one who buys it, never uses it. The one that uses it never knows that he's using it. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("The more you have of it, the less you see. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("I am always hungry, i must be fed, the finger i touch will soon turn red. What am i ?");
        riddles.add("If you break me, i do not stop working, if you touch me, i may snared, if you lose me, nothing will matter. What am i ?");

        answers.add("Matches");
        answers.add("Nothing");
        answers.add("Man");
        answers.add("Letter E");
        answers.add("River");
        answers.add("The Stars");
        answers.add("A Coffin");
        answers.add("Darkness");
        answers.add("Fire");
        answers.add("Heart");

        Random random = new Random();

        riddleQuestionTextView.setText(riddles.get(riddleCounter));

        locationOfCorrectAnswers = random.nextInt(4);

        options.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i == locationOfCorrectAnswers) {
                options.add(answers.get(riddleCounter));
            }else {
                incorrectAnswers = random.nextInt(riddles.size());
                while (incorrectAnswers == riddleCounter) {
                    incorrectAnswers = random.nextInt(riddles.size());
                }
                options.add(answers.get(incorrectAnswers));
            }
        }
        btn1.setText(options.get(0));
        btn2.setText(options.get(1));
        btn3.setText(options.get(2));
        btn4.setText(options.get(3));
    }
```

Comment: iterate through a loop and check if options already has that String

Comment: Use an iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

        if (i == locationOfCorrectAnswers && 
                    !options.contains(answers.get(riddleCounter))) {

                options.add(answers.get(riddleCounter));

        }else {

            incorrectAnswers = random.nextInt(riddles.size());

            while (incorrectAnswers == riddleCounter) {

                incorrectAnswers = random.nextInt(riddles.size());
            }

             if(!options.contains(answers.get(incorrectAnswers)))
                   options.add(answers.get(incorrectAnswers));
             else --i;
        }

    }
```

that should prevent duplicates

EDIT: added full code

EDIT2: fixed indexOutOfBounds exception

Comment: Thanks for helping out, but if i may ask where do i put the if block code

Comment: @Tunjixy i have added some more code, so you know exactly where to place it. If it helped, do upvote and select as answer! :)

Comment: @ hello_world i have tried the code it's works, but now the correct answers are now duplicating on the button but the incorrect answers are not

Comment: @Tunjixy thats strange, should not happen. Anyway, just add the extra line and you should be good  to go!

Comment: @ hello_world it's no more duplicating the answers anymore, but am getting an java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255),

Comment: @Tunjixy my bad, forgot about the edge case. Anyway, this should do it. just merge the two if statements.

Comment: the code is working perfectly fine now, no exception, and no duplication, but now when the user plays the game, it's sometimes get the correct answer to be wrong answer, and the wrong answer to be correct answer, any ideas why that is happening

Comment: why dont you add a few log statements and see if you can reproduce the results. its all trial and error buddy! Also, do select this as answer and upvote!

Comment: i need your help, the app is working and have been able to debug the bug, the bug is that the correct answer is showing up in the wrong location, how do i fix these

Comment: @Tunjixy does this happen all the time? or just a few edge cases?

Comment: it's happens in a few edge cases

Comment: Okay. Can you add some log statements in the loop for the values of i in each iteration and post it?

Comment: sorry, but how do i do that?

Comment: Is there any other way i can fix it..., it a project from school, i really need your  help

Comment: I would ask you to check the code again.. Is it the same exact code I gave? Just to be sure, replace it again and check. I do not know why it would not work. And also, the few times it does not work, is the answer always in two specific positions? Or is it always changing?

Comment: have checked it again, its still the same, and the answers is always changing... i just wanted to ask if you have another way to create a guess app, i just have 1 week to submit this project. Thanks for your help....